# Messaging Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, messaging

I have a consumer that consumes multiple messages, all messages share a property that tells me its "type"

Is there a better way to do this without the massive switch statement I have going on?

```
 switch (type)
            {
                // Commands
                
                case nameof(CreateUserCommand):
                    await _dispatcher.Dispatch(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateUserCommand>(message));
                    break;
                
                case nameof(DeleteUserCommand):
                    await _dispatcher.Dispatch(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeleteUserCommand>(message));
                    break;
                
                case nameof(EditUserCommand):
                    await _dispatcher.Dispatch(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EditUserCommand>(message));
                    break;
```

Dispatch Method that they go to

```
        public async Task Dispatch<TMessage>(TMessage message)
        {
            var handlers = _provider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IMessageHandler<TMessage>>>().ToList();

            if(handlers.Any() == false) throw new Exception($"No handlers for message {message.GetType().Name}");
                
            foreach (var consumer in handlers)
            {
                await consumer.Handle(message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is, take a look at the [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki) library

With it, you define the commands that implements the IRequest interface, and the handlers that implements the IRequestHandler interface.

Take a look at the documentation I sent above, it's pretty straight forward.

Message:

```
public class Ping : IRequest<string> { }
```

Handler:

```
public class PingHandler : IRequestHandler<Ping, string>
{
    public Task<string> Handle(Ping request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Pong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yer, I already know about this library, I just wanted to not pollute my contracts library with third-party nuget packages

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, your type is a string.

You will need to convert this to the real type first.. It is important to include the namespace also for the type! When you have the type, you can use one of the overloaded methods.

```
Type userCommand = Type.GetType(type);
await _dispatcher.Dispatch(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, userCommand));
```

Comment: Seems to just convert it to JsonObject? 

System.Exception : No handlers for message JObject

Comment: Ok got it to convert to its type, but doesn't actually find any handlers because its an object and not the actual type?

Comment: Can you separate the await from the call by placing the return in a var and debug to see what it is you got returned (I do not have running code): var x = _dispatcher.Dis...